# MySQL Insert date log

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find out when something was added to a database I maintain but the script that adds the date was working.

Is there a way to retrieve the date of the original INSERT command?

Comment: if your question is ansered then please mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html

Answer (score 1):

make a new table with the key of the table to watch create a after insert trigger that inserts a new line into the watchout table with the id and the time inserted